# Which RDF predicates to use to annotate: fileX "has hash" 01ABCF "of type" sha256 "downloaded from site" http://url/to/page?

Tags: rdf, ontology

Which predicates to use:

(let's use [Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(syntax)) syntax)

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix file: <http://domain.I.own/my_rdf_space_for_file_ids/> .
@prefix q?: <predicates and entifies I am looking for>

file:f20160905_00123456
   dc:title "Example Site with Video" ;
   q?:downloaded_from "http://url_to_size/video_xyz12345"
   q?:has_hash [
     q?:hash_type q?:sha256;
     q?:hash_value "literal_with_hash_value_01234ACBDEF"
   ] .
```

The more standard/canonical predicates, the better :)

( `@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .` ? Schema.org ?).

Use case:

- I have url of site of given video, let it be some vimeo video.
- URL does not result to file directly
- However main content is video
- Which I can stream of download in various resolutioms
- So I downloades on of those for offline view
- And got file with given hash
- Now I'd like to make assisting '.ttl' file, with annotation that given hash is hasg of given type and payload comes from site od given url.

Comment: Look at [this set](https://developer.gnome.org/ontology/stable/ontology.html) of ontologies.

Answer (score 1):

Use Wikipedia urls to identify the hash type.
(That's [5 star](https://ontotext.com/knowledgehub/fundamentals/five-star-linked-open-data/) out of the box)

For your other questions use [Linked Open Vocabularies](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/terms).

If that fails, use your own URLs (5 star please) and if you later on discover, that there are more appropriate URLs for it, add and distribute `owl:sameAs` or `rdfs:subPropertyOf` triples alongside your data (depending on what level formality you use).

Comment: Ok, so you've suggested rdf:object to be wikipedia or wikidata url. What about rdf:predicate, which I noted as :has_hash ?

Comment: Also what about defining source "X comes_from webpage_Y" ?

Comment: Have a look at the PROV (provenance) ontology for your second comment. I don't get the first, though (Sorry have been offline from OpenData for a while)